# Which one is correct65 year old or 65 years old?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure about the plural s so is it do I need a hyphen as well
but people is singular 
I suggest the second is right

...65 year old people

or

...65 years old people??

Answer (score 0):

'65 year[s] old' is an example of a measurement phrase.  It literally means: 'as old as 65 years'.  When used as an adjective, the unit should be singular.  When used as a complement, the unit should be plural if the quantity is plural (not singular).

All 65 year old people are 65 years old.

A six foot long board is six feet long.

A one foot long board is one foot long.

Comment: Hyphenating these phrases is not yet entirely obsolete: *65-year-old* people, *six-foot-long* board, *day-old* bread.